# Agregar elemento a array Json con Gson

Tags: java, json, gson

Este es mi archivo Json:

```
[{"nombre":"Activo","valor": 8500},{"nombre":"Pasivo","valor":500000}]
```

Y quiero agregar a la ultima posicion de ese array otro objeto utilizando Gson, yo probe lo siguiente:

```
public void add(Cuenta cuenta) throws IOException{

    String cuentaSerializada = myGson.toJson(cuenta);
    this.writeJson(cuentaSerializada);
}

private void writeJson(String cuentaSerialized) throws IOException{
    this.bufferToWrite = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(this.filePath, true));
    this.bufferToWrite.append(cuentaSerialized);
    this.bufferToWrite.close();
}
```

Pero lo unico que hace es agregar un objeto fuera del array:

```
 [{"nombre":"Activo","valor": 8500},{"nombre":"Pasivo","valor":500000}]{"nombre":"Patrimonio","valor":152000}
```

Utilizo Java en Eclipse

Comment: ¿Tendrias algún test unitario de las pruebas que realizas?

Answer (score 1):

Lo que estás haciendo es un append al archivo, por lo que es lógico que después del último caractér ] , se adjunte tu String, quedando así fuera del arreglo.

Deberías hacer un JsonArray de tu archivo, luego un JsonElement con tu nueva entrada, meter el Element en el Array, y entonces convertir el Array en Json utilizando Gson.